# В чем заключается отличие перечисления с битовым флагом от обычного перечисления?

Tags: c#, .net

Чем различается перечисление, объявленное так:

```
[Flags]
public enum ASD
{
    None = 0,
    Param1 = 1,
    Param2 = 2,
    Param3 = 4,
}
```

или так

```
public enum ASD
{
    None = 0,
    Param1 = 1,
    Param2 = 2,
    Param3 = 4,
}
```

Comment: [_Flags itself does nothing. Also, C# does not require Flags per se. But the ToString implementation of your enum uses Flags, and so does Enum.IsDefined, Enum.Parse, etc. Try to remove Flags and look at the result of MyColor.Yellow | MyColor.Red; without it you get "5", with Flags you get "Yellow, Red". Some other parts of the framework also use Flags, e.g., XML Serialization._](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c#comment1119528_8480). В двух словах атрибут ничего не делает, но может поменяться поведение некоторых функций

Comment: [похожий вопрос на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Этот атрибут означает, что значения перечисления, к которому он применяется, могут рассматриваться как битовые поля и к ним можно применять битовые операции, что отразится, в частности, на поведении метода ToString.

Например:

```
// если перечисление помечено атрибутом
ASD flags = (ASD)5;
Console.WriteLine(flags); // выведет Param1, Param3

// если перечисление не помечено атрибутом
ASD enums = (ASD)5;          
Console.WriteLine(enums); // выведет 5
```

Comment: Битовые операции можно применять и к обычному перечислению, я проверил только что. Ну не же существовать битовый флаг просто так.

Comment: @Prisoner можно, только поведение будет несколько иным. Я добавил пример

Comment: Console.WriteLine(flags.ToString("F")); // выведет также Param1, Param3 вне зависимости от наличия аттрибута [Flags]

Answer (score 4):

С точки зрения механизма работы - этот атрибут меняет поведение метода `ToString()`

Без атрибута:

```
((ASD)3).ToString() == "3";
```

С атрибутом:

```
((ASD)3).ToString() == "Param1, Param2";
```

Comment: ээээх :-) я слишком долго набираю текст :-D

Comment: На статические методы, похоже этот атрибут не влияет, только `ToString`

Comment: @Grundy хм, забавно - но да. Parse парсит списки значений даже для обычных перечислений...

Comment: @Grundy кстати, это я дописал после того как ваш комментарий увидел :)

Comment: Ага, это потому что была цитата комментария, а ему там потом говорят, что типа ты не совсем прав с этими методами :)