# Switch-Case с перечислением С#

Tags: c#, enum

Такая проблема. Есть перечисление

```
[Flags]
public enum SortType
{
    Amount = 0,
    Consumptions = 1,
    Date = 2,
    Description = 3,
    Group = 4,
    Incomes = 5,
    Kind = 6, 
    Counterparty = 7,
    Type = 8,
    Valute = 9
}
```

По не му нужно пройтись switch-caseом, учитывая компоновку, потому что нужно выбрать множество вариантов для сортировки, но при некоторых раскладах, вроде следующего, появляется ошибка:

```
case SortType.Consumptions:
    break;
case SortType.Consumptions | SortType.Date:
    break;
//Предложение Switch содержит несколько случаев со значением "3" (Откуда, если в данном контексте оно впервые?)
case SortType.Consumptions | SortType.Description:
    break;
case SortType.Consumptions | SortType.Group:
    break;
//Предложение Switch содержит несколько случаев со значением "5" (То же самое)
case SortType.Consumptions | SortType.Incomes:
```

И так повторяется на каждое нечётное число. Хотя в похожем коде (вместо Consumprions стоит Amount) ошибок нет. Что делать?

Comment: `//Предложение Switch содержит несколько случаев со значением "3"` - `Description = 3,` и `Consumptions | Date` тоже =3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы корректно работали побитовые операции, каждый флаг должен занимать свой отдельный бит:

```
[Flags]
public enum SortType
{
    Amount = 0,
    Consumptions = 1 << 0,
    Date = 1 << 1,
    Description = 1 << 2,
    Group = 1 << 3,
    Incomes = 1 << 4,
    Kind = 1 << 5, 
    Counterparty = 1 << 6,
    Type = 1 << 7,
    Valute = 1 << 8
}
```

Иначе получается что, например, Description  - это уже побитовое пересечение Consumptions  и Date.

Answer (score 3):

При работе с флагами, желательно, чтобы значения соответствовали отдельным битам, например:

```
1 (0b0000001)
2 (0b0000010)
4 (0b0000100)
8 (0b0001000)
```

и т.д.

Это позволит при использовании битового ИЛИ получать одно значение, соответствующее сразу двум флагам, при этом это значение будет уникальным для любой комбинации флагов и по нему всегда можно будет сказать, с помощью каких флагов оно образовано.

В вопросе, значения перечисления идут по порядку, в связи с этим возникают коллизии, когда одно значение можно получить несколькими способами, например:

```
Incomes = 5
Consumptions | Group = 5
Date | Description = 5
```

Именно на это и ругается `switch`.

---

В связи с этим может возникнуть вопрос, а что же делает атрибут `Flags`, собственно, [ничего не делает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/585880/186999)